# ListView not displaying data from database

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I'm trying to display a column of data from a database in WPF through a listview. Here's my code:

```
private void OpenExistingBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    OpenOrNew.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    OpenExisting.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
    con.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
    cmd.CommandText = "select docName from [table]";
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    da.Fill(dt);
    dataTable.DataContext = dt.DefaultView;
    con.Close();
}
```

My XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="OpenExisting" Visibility="Collapsed">
    <Grid Background="Black" Opacity="0.5">
        <Border MinWidth="250" Background="{x:Null}" BorderThickness="0" CornerRadius="4" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
            <ListView x:Name="dataTable">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView>
                        <GridViewColumn Header="Select a file" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=docName}"></GridViewColumn>
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
        </Border>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

There is definitely data in my database, and there are no errors when running the code.
This is what my database looks like:

[image: This is what my database looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set your `ListView.ItemsSource` property to `dataTable.DefaultView`. Example:

`OpenExisting.ItemsSource = dt.DefaultView`